# How to Check whether there is any values in NSMutable Array?

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray

I am developing an application, in which I am getting the values from the URL, for example, take it as (demo.png), here what I am doing is, i am separating the string with       `<componentsSeparatedByString:@"." >` and saving that in the `array (Index 0 : demo & Index 1: png )`. And, it works fine. Now, what i getting struck here, when the value from the URL doesn't contain `".png, .jpeg"` then error message is coming. How can i check whether there is a value in ObjectAtIndex:1 is null. What i did for this was,

Coding :

```
if ([array45 objectAtIndex:1] == NSNULL NULL) {
   NSLog(@"object at index %i has no data", i);
}
```

Error message:

```
[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
```

Help me with your valuable solutions.

Comment: hi if there in not any array at index 1 then how can we check for that...it will give crash because you are accessing the object which are not present.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSArray *aray = [@"demo.png" componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];

if ([[aray lastObject] isEqualToString:@"png"])
{
    NSLog(@"There is an image with .png");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"There is no image eith .png extension");
}
```

Comment: make this condition for jpg and jpeg also..if u want

Answer (score 0):

First you want to find out how many objects are in the array.

```
int count = [array count];
```

If you don't have the correct count you don't check what's in an index.